# Deriving the formula for the Quartic

Tags: polynomials

Could someone explain to me how was the Quartic formula originally derivated?

Is there any simple 'modern' method for deriving it? How does Galois theory help?

[image]

Comment: Modern methods would be through Galois theory.

Comment: see here http://www.curtisbright.com/quartic/quartic-derivation.html

Comment: @Bernard could you provide me a reference to that?

Comment: You just write $x^4 + b x^3 + c x^2 + d x + e = 0$ as $(x^2 + (b/2) x)^2 = (b^2/4 -c)x^2 -d x - e$ Then add a parameter p inside the brackets on the l.h.s. and work out what the r.h.s. as a function of p is. You then choose p such that the r.h.s. becomes a perfect square, i.e. you set the discriminant of the quadratic equal to zero, which yields a third degree equation for p.

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD: I'd recommend David Cox's *Galois theory* (Wiley-Interscience, 2004) which has numerous examples, includes a historical point of view, and discusses Lagrange's resolvents. For quartics, see Ch. 12 *Lagrange, Galois, and Kronecker*, §12.1 C.